# Crystal Reports Custom IsNull Function

Tags: function, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008

I am trying to create a custom IsNull Function in Crystal Reports; the function must act the same way as the IsNull Function in MS SQL Server. I want to specify a field, and if the field is null, then it must be returned with a value I have specified.

```
IsNull({myField},0) or
IsNull({myField},'Hello World')
```

I have encountered that I have to create a separate function for number fields and a separate function for text fields. I also found that Crystal does not allow the use of standard functions inside of a custom function, for instance the `ISNULL` Function:

```
Function(NumberVar param, Numbervar setter)
IF ISNULL(param) THEN setter ELSE param
```

and

```
Function(StringVar param, StringVar setter)
IF param = NULL THEN setter ELSE param
```

Does anyone know how I can create a function like this in Crystal and a work around for the `ISNULL` inside of a custom function?

Answer (score 11):

You can't pass a null value into a custom function, so it's pointless to use crystal's `isnull` function inside one. Only option is to write it like...

```
if isnull({myField}) then 0 else {myField}
```

Answer (score 11):

I found this issue, in the formula editor there is a drop down in the header that indicates:

- Exception for Nulls
- Default values for nulls

Select the second one ( Default values for nulls)

Answer (score 2):

I've encountered the same behavior, but I have yet to see a documented reason for this.

I would suggest that you use a SQL Expression:

```
//{%myField}
(
  ISNULL({myField},'Hello World') 
)
```

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

```
if  (isnull({dbvalue}) or ({dbvalue} ='')) then 
       "Display the required text"
else
       {dbvalue}
```